# LifecycleService not found

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I am trying to extend `LifecycleService`. I have implemented the following in `build.gradle`

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
```

The below line gives error:

```
internal class MyService: LifecycleService() {
```

> Unresolved reference: LifecycleService

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per the [Lifecycle Declaring dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies), you need to use `lifecycle-service` to use `LifecycleService`:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.2.0"
```

(This would in addition to `lifecycle-runtime-ktx`)

Comment: I wish they could write it there in the IDE instead of us thinking something terrible went wrong, needing to search about it over the Internet and even ask about it here...